# Writing query with where clause in Python NDB

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, python-2.x, ndb

So I have a query that looks like

```
 data = ndb.Key('Account', int(entity_id)).get()
```

is it possible to add a where clause and filter by other fields

Comment: That won't work, but it would be helpful to explain what you are trying to accomplish with `field_name`.

Comment: so my goal is that I am trying to query the entity Account but instead of filtring with key e.g 000000001 like the id 
'i want to use another field ' e.g where status = "open"

Comment: For that, you need to use ndb.query()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, you need to use ndb.query() –
@gaefan comment